# Crash when adding a UINavigationController - swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Crash when adding a UINavigationController. 
I'm using this library and sample code:

https://github.com/appssemble/appstore-card-transition

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "type2") as! Type2ViewController

// Get tapped cell location
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell
cell.settings.cardContainerInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8.0, left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0)
cell.settings.isEnabledBottomClose = bottomDismiss

transition = CardTransition(cell: cell, settings: cell.settings)
viewController.settings = cell.settings
viewController.transitioningDelegate = transition
viewController.subtitle = "Bottom dismissible"
viewController.background = UIImage(named: "type2-bg-bottom")

viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom   
presentExpansion(viewController, cell: cell, animated: true)
```

Xcode Error logs:

```
Class AppstoreTransition.CardPresentationController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1049b1338) to 'AppstoreTransition.CardsViewController' (0x1049b1308).
2019-06-29 15:39:24.077448+0200 TechSpec[10118:1200941] Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1049b1338) to 'AppstoreTransition.CardsViewController' (0x1049b1308).
```

Comment: Sounds like your subclass overrides `traitCollection` which it’s saying isn’t allowed.

Comment: @DanielStorm Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: The actual issue is the casting problem. Most likely your storyboard is claiming that the UINavigationController is actually a CardsViewController when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

Force unwrapping values (using !) is in general bad practice and can (and should) be avoided most times. Force unwrapping guarantees to totally crash your app if somehow there is nothing to unwrap (nil).

Instead you should use something like if let or guard let, e.g.

```
guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CardCollectionViewCell else { debugPrint("uh-oh nil in here "; return }
```

or with an if let:

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CardCollectionViewCell {
    // your other code
} else {
    // handling the case when your cell is not of type CardCollectionViewCell
}
```

**My guess for fixing your bug:**

You did not set your custom class (inside your storyboard) to CardCollectionViewCell. See the example of a personal project below to find the right input field in Xcode. The example is for a TableView, but for your CollectionView it is the same.

- You have to select your custom cell
- Type in your custom class name
- Press Enter.

Otherwise, your cell will be a UICollectionViewCell by default.

[image: screenshot xcode storyboard, setting custom class]

In case you initialised your storyboard-cell via code, check if you really did initialize a cell of your custom type and not a UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: This is actually a case where you do want to force-unwrap (cast). The cell should be a known type and the force-cast should be what you do. You want the app to crash early during development if the cast fails so you can fix your code.

Comment: And note that error has nothing to do with the cell. It's about a UINavigationController being cast to a CardsViewController. The code in the question has nothing to do with the actual issue.

Comment: You are right, that the code has nothing to do with the error. But the solution could be similar to my posted screenshot.

Maybe it is fine to use force casts during early development and it is also shown in a lot of tutorials to force unwrap custom cell stuff. But what if the cast does not fail? You can not say that it will never fail on a user's device. I think it is just good practice to handle all possible cases instead of giving the app a chance to crash just to save some characters of code.